# How can put an array in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I have a problem, I need put an array in a DataGridView, I have the next code, but only I obtain the positions of the array with the rows, but the rows are empty...

Can anyone help me?

```
int[] arrays = new int [CaminoHormiga.Length];
string periodohorario = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < CaminoHormiga.Length; i++)
{
    arrays = CaminoHormiga;
    periodohorario = arrays[i].ToString();

    hg.dgHorarioGen.DataSource = arrays;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
List<int> arrays = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < CaminoHormiga.Length; i++)
{
   arrays.Add(CaminoHormiga);
}

hg.dgHorarioGen.DataSource = arrays;
```

Comment: i can find the answer, i had an error with the positions in code, thanks anyway!

Comment: can you please give me the error, my answer is not tested, my apologize :)